# Discord bot that deletes messages by "x" amount in python

Tags: python, discord, bots

So the bot I created (in python) can currently delete all messages with the command "!clear all". However, I would also like to add a function to it, so that people can type in "x" amount and for that to be deleted instead of all. Is this possible? or would I need to redo this function a different way?
I should add I'm new to python and still learning the ropes.

Here is my code:

````py
if '!clear all' in message.content and message.author.permissions_in(message.channel).manage_messages:
    await message.channel.send('__**This will delete all messages (even pinned)**__')
    await message.channel.send('**Type:**')
    await message.channel.send('```"!yes" to continue```')
    await message.channel.send('```"!no" to stop```')
if '!no' in message.content and message.author.permissions_in(message.channel).manage_messages:
    await message.channel.send('**This proccess has stopped**')
    exit()
else:
    if '!yes' in message.content and message.author.permissions_in(message.channel).manage_messages:
        await message.channel.send('**This proccess will continue in:**')
        await message.channel.send('**3**')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        await message.channel.send('**2**')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        await message.channel.send('**1**')
        deleted = await message.channel.purge(limit=3000)
        await message.channel.send('**All messages deleted. Have a nice day**'.format(deleted))
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        deleted = await message.channel.purge(limit=3000)
````

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Discord.py` actually provides functionality to implement something like this, you can add parameters to your command via [function arguments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters), and you can ask `discord.py` to automatically convert them to specific types (such as `integer/numbers`) with [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#basic-converters).

If you're not using `discord.py` or `commands` yet, I recommend you do, it helps a lot!

To solve the question without these features though, you can take the user input (here `message.content` and `split` it after every space (`message_arguments = message.content.split()`) this will give you a list of words (where `message_arguments[0]` is the command, here `!clear`, and message_arguments[1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters) is the second argument, for example `all` or potentially a number) and from there you need to check whether that second argument is `all` or a number by using `int(message_arguments[1])`, more on that [here](https://realpython.com/convert-python-string-to-int/) for example. Once you have the number you can simply use it as a variable and use it to delete the messages: `await message.channel.purge(limit=variable_that_holds_a_number)`.